# WebApplication unable to find assembly Microsoft.ServiceBus after first success

Tags: c#, .net, servicebus

We are in an MVC webapplication project using Microsofts ServiceBus as a queue. The customer places an order which is then processed by a backend system, after it is complete it sends a response back to the WebApp via the servicebus.

The first time we trigger this flow everything works fine. The second time the flow is executed the WebApplication has the following error:

```
Application ID: DefaultDomain

Process ID: 3504

Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap.Create(String name, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
```

If we restart the Application Pool and the site, everything is back to square one. It works the first time, but then subsequently fails. We only have this behaviour on a new live environment that we are about to publish. Everything  works locally and in our current live environment. So this has to be about the          environment. We have our environments on-site, only the ServiceBus is in Azure.

ServiceBus: "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="2.4.8.0". I have also tried with version 2.6.0 with the same result.

One thing that differs the new environment from old is that it is Windows 2012 server instead of 2010, as well as IIS 8 instead of IIS 7. The hardware resources on the new environment are at fine levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue and solved it by installing

- HTTP Activation
- TCP Activation

Under .NET Framework 4.5 Features

Best regards,
Frank